# Particle library

Tags: c++, open-source, particles

maybe someone knows a good crossplatform particle library?

I know [Pyro](http://pyro.fenomen-games.com/) particle library, but it's not crossplaftorm and free. There is also [Magic Particles](http://www.astralax.com/projects/particles) (Probably, the best version I need) but there is only theoretical possibility to make a port on Linux.

Comment: Would making one your self be out of the question? They are a relatively simple thing, in theory :P the only hard thing is you need to build you particle class, something that the particle engine will just manage, so that it responds how you want it to. You would need both a particle, and a particle manager.

Comment: @thecoshman I have my own simple particle code. It's very simple and I want to have a more power in this question.

Comment: The temptation to suggest [Geant](http://www.geant4.org/geant4/) or [GENIE](http://projects.hepforge.org/genie/) is *almost* overwhelming...

Comment: I think there should be one lib per answer and on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how good it is, but I remember seeing a post on www.gamedev.net on a open source particle engine written in C++.  It appears to be graphics-library agnostic, so you should be able to easily port it to whatever platform you are interested in.

Here's a link:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sparkengine/

Comment: I ended up using this in my own game and it's quite good. Also ended up writing a shaders-based OpenGL render library.